# How to pass multiple arguments in functions with pointers?

Tags: c

I want to calculate the area and volume of the sphere by typing the radius size using this function below. How do I pass the arguments and get the results using pointers?

```
void calc_sphere(float radius, float *area, float *volume)
```

I know the basics:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.1415
main()
{
float radius, area, volume;
printf("enter the value of radius: ");
scanf("%f", &radius);
area = 4*PI*radius*radius;
volume = (4/3)*PI*radius*radius;
printf("area of sphere is %f\n", area);
printf("volume of sphere is %f", volume);
}
```

Comment: Hint: Do you see how `radius` is passed by address to `scanf`? Passing `area` and `volume` by address to `calc-sphere` will be not-surprisingly similar.

Comment: `(4/3)` is `1` due to integer division. It should be `(4.0/3)`, and `radius` *cubed*.

Comment: Normally you pass in by value and return by value unless you have structures or *need* mutable arguments. This could be `float calc_sphere_volume(float radius)` and `float calc_sphere_area(float radius)` instead of one bizarrely multi-purpose function.

Comment: Tip: Check for `PI` in `math.h` and avoid defining it yourself, especially to such a weak level of precision.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the address of a variable, there you would be able to write or read its value (dereferencing the pointer):

https://wandbox.org/permlink/SZUD2Gcu5yytmDKt

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int* a, int* b) {
    *a = 10;
    *b = 11;
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    
    printf("Before: %d %d\n", a, b);    
    func(&a,&b);
    printf("After: %d %d\n", a , b);
}
```

The output will be:

```
Before: 0 1
After: 10 11
```

Comment: I tried to adapt.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JoseCarlos you can add your new code to the original post